# JSONAPI Resources: undefined method serialize_to_hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, jsonapi-resources

I am using the gem `jsonapi-resources` `0.10.5`.

This is my resource:

```
class ProjectResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attributes :name
end
```

and this is my controller:

```
class V2::ProjectController < V2::BaseController
    def index
        project = Project.find(1)
        JSONAPI::ResourceSerializer.new(ProjectResource).serialize_to_hash(ProjectResource.new(project, nil), nil) 
    end
end
```

and I get this error:

> NoMethodError in V2::ProjectTypesController#index undefined method
> `serialize_to_hash' for
> #JSONAPI::ResourceSerializer:0x00007ffabcc336b0

I am just following the docs:

https://jsonapi-resources.com/v0.10/guide/serializer.html

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: `serialize_to_hash` appears to exist in [master](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources/blob/master/lib/jsonapi/resource_serializer.rb#L46) but not in [0.10.5](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources/blob/v0.10.5/lib/jsonapi/resource_serializer.rb)?

Comment: that makes sense, so why does the documentation says to add `gem 'jsonapi-resources'` to the Gemfile and then use `serialize_to_hash` if the version `0.10.5` doesn't contain that method?

Comment: Bad documentation? You could open an issue in git about this if you felt so inclined.

Comment: Yeah, most probably. Could you please write an asnwer? I will be happy to upvote/accept your answer.